# PrintedPDFDocument results in PDF containing Grey box with sort of Grid Layout

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

After many problems, I have finally been able to generate a PDF Document that has content and isn't corrupted using the PrintedPDFClass.

The problem is, however, the content in the PDF doesn't seem to bear any relation to the VIew I gave it to render...

The view that I want to render:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:kingdomspas="http://www.kingdomspas.com/android/custom"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/salesAgreementTableLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TableLayout>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/companyLogo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/logo_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />

                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/companyAddress"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/address_description"
                    android:src="@drawable/company_address" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/salesExecInitials"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/round"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:paddingLeft="130dp"
                            android:singleLine="true" >

                            <requestFocus />
                        </EditText>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="@string/sales_exec_initials" />
                    </FrameLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/salesExecInitials"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/round"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="130dp"
                        android:singleLine="true" >

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/sales_exec_initials" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <View
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/submitButton"
            android:text="@string/submit_form"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Which results in a UI like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The code I use to generate the PDF is:

```
Builder printAttrsBuilder = new Builder();
        printAttrsBuilder.setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4);
        printAttrsBuilder.setMinMargins(new Margins(5, 5, 5, 5));



        PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, printAttrsBuilder.build());

        PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(150, 150, 1).create();
        Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        Canvas pdfCanvas = page.getCanvas();
        salesFragmentTableLayout.draw(page.getCanvas());
        document.finishPage(page);
        File result = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos= null;
        FileDescriptor descriptor = null;
        try {
            result = File.createTempFile("Kingdom Spas Agreement", ".pdf", context.getCacheDir());
            fos = new FileOutputStream(result);
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            document.writeTo(bos);
            descriptor = fos.getFD();
            descriptor.sync();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new KingdomSpasException("Failed to find relevent file", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new KingdomSpasException("IO Problem occured while creatin the PDF", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bos != null) { bos.flush(); bos.close(); }
            } catch (SyncFailedException e) {
                throw new KingdomSpasException("Failed to correctly sync PDF file - may be corrupted", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new KingdomSpasException("Failed to correctly clean up streams", e);
            }
        }
        document.close();
```

But the PDF that is created looks like (viewing at 100% zoom):

[image: Resulting PDF]

Can anyone explain to me why the resulting PDf is (to my eyes at least) so different from my Original view and explain how to fix it?

Edit:  Here's a link to the generated PDF in case that rovides any useful information:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/134344/KingdomSpasAgreement.pdf

Comment: where are you actually rendering a view ?

Comment: The view is rendered in the initial activity fragment and, when the user clicks the button, the view is then drawn to as pdf.

Comment: you need to show your whole code.

Comment: Try removing the PageInfo stuff. You don't need it since you only have 1 page, and you already described that the page size you want is ISO_A4.

Besides, you need to show what `salesFragmentTableLayout.draw(page.getCanvas());` is doing, because it might be culprit of you having only a grey box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder.html#PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(int,%20int,%20int)):

> ```
> public PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder (int pageWidth, int pageHeight, int pageNumber)
> ```
>
> Creates a new builder with the mandatory page info attributes.
>
> Parameters
>
> *pageWidth*   The page width in PostScript (1/72th of an inch).
>
> *pageHeight*  The page height in PostScript (1/72th of an inch).
>
> *pageNumber*  The page number.

You use a

```
PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(150, 150, 1).create();
Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
```

So, you create a page merely about 2 in x 2 in in size. In this small area only a part of the submit button fits. (The PDF page content actually even contains the string "Submit" but it is far outside the viewable area.)

As you are using the `PrintedPdfDocument`, you should instead use:

```
Page page = document.startPage(1);
```

> *(cf. [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument.html) again)*

Comment: maybe this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html#draw-content) can help